# Javascript assign json keys to variables

Tags: json

I have a json object, for example:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

And I need to read it, but I need to get variables with same names as the keys:

```
key1 = value1;
key2 = value2;
key3 = value3;
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: If you already know the keys, just unpack it: `const { key1, key2, key3 } = obj;`. Otherwise, do not pollute your namespace by creating variables dynamically - just leave them in the object.

Comment: Yes, I thought about assigning variables to make the code cleaner, because I'm going to use them in templates. But, your suggestion is simple. With dot notation it will also be clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JSON *string* you can parse it, and split it up in 3 variables with:

```js
const { key1, key2, key3 } = JSON.parse('...');
```

If you have a Javascript *object*, it's pretty similar:

```js
const { key1, key2, key3 } = myObj;
```